# jquery ui tab not posting data to asp.net(c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

**The HTML for jqueryUI tabs.**

```
<div id="lodg_tabs" class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Add/Remove</a></li>
        <li><a href="mand_lodg_upd.aspx">Update</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" class="forms">
        <h3 align="center">Mandate Lodgment</h3>
        <form name="mand_lodg" id="mand_lodg" method="post">
```

**ajax code to send parameters to the tab loading "mand_lodg_upd.aspx"**

```
$("#lodg_tabs").tabs({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var res = valid('mand_lodg');
        $(this).tabs("option", { ajaxOptions: { data: $("#mand_lodg").serialize()} });
     },
     ajaxOptions: {
         type: 'POST',
         error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
             $(anchor.hash).html("An error has been encountered while attempting to load this tab.");
         }
     },
     cache: false
});
```

**the c# code behind**

```
Response.Write(Request.Form["zone"] + Request.QueryString["zone"]);
            zone.Value = Request.Form["zone"];
            loc.Value = Request.Form["loc"];
            date.Value = Request.Form["date"];
```

**The output:** Output is ok, the file is loading in the tab

**The problem :** but the parameters passed with ajax i.e

```
$(this).tabs("option", { ajaxOptions: { data: $("#mand_lodg").serialize()} });
```

zone location and date are null in c# code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request.Form is referring to HTTP request parameters via the POST method.  JQuery by default issues a GET method request. Try setting your AJAX Options like so:

```
$(this).tabs("option", { 
    ajaxOptions: { 
                   type: 'post', 
                   data: $("#mand_lodg").serialize()
                 } 
});
```

Comment: Request.QueryString["zone"] is also giving null then. I hope QueryString is to extract from get method.

Comment: Request.QueryString should work.  Can you provide the form to your code above... are you setting the name attribute of the elements you are posting?

Comment: Request.QueryString was not working anyhow the above ans helped, I kept type as post. thankyou. Still I would like to know y Request.QueryString is not working :)

Comment: Reviewing some code, to send the querystring I believe you have to set the AJAXOption 'url'.  So it would be { url: '[webpage]?' + $("#mand_lodg").serialize()}.  The AJAXOption 'data' only sends when you POST to the server, but you can always use Request.QueryString to parse the requested url.